# Array of struct pointers and assigning struct data

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have run into a problem or maybe I am just doing something wrong since I am new to C and structs.  I want to take a text file such as this:

```
3
Trev,CS,3.5
Joe,ART,2.5
Bob,ESC,1.0
```

and read in the first line as the number of students then from there out gather student info and put them in a struct called StudentData:

```
typedef struct StudentData{
   
    char* name;
    char* major;
    double gpa;
  
} Student;
```

Where I run into a problem is after I seemingly assign the data to an individual struct, the struct data becomes mixed up.  I have commented out exactly what is going on (or at least what I believe is).  Hopefully it isn't painful to read.

```
main(){
    int size, i;
    char* line = malloc(100);
    scanf("%d\n", &size);//get size
    char* tok;
    char* temp;
    Student* array[size]; //initialize array of Student pointers

    for(i = 0; i<size;i++){
      array[i] = malloc(sizeof(Student));//allocate memory to Student pointed to by array[i]
      array[i]->name = malloc(50); //allocate memory for Student's name
      array[i]->major = malloc(30);//allocate memory for Student's major
    }
    
    for(i = 0; i<size;i++){
      scanf("%s\n", line);//grab student info and put it in a string
      tok = strtok(line, ","); //tokenize string, taking name first
      array[i]->name = tok;//assign name to Student's name attribute
//    printf("%s\n",array[i]->name);//prints correct value
      line = strtok(NULL, ",");//tokenize
      array[i]->major = line;//assign major to Student's major attribute
//    printf("%s\n",array[i]->major);//prints correct value
      temp = strtok(NULL, ",");//tokenize
      array[i]->gpa = atof(temp);//assign gpa to Student's gpa attribute
//    printf("%.2f\n\n",array[i]->gpa); //prints correct value
    }
    
    for(i=0;i<size;i++){ //this loop is where the data becomes jumbled
      printf("%s\n",array[i]->name);
      printf("%s\n",array[i]->major);
      printf("%.2f\n\n",array[i]->gpa);
  }
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
Trev
Joe
3.50

Joe
Bob
2.50

Bob
ESC
1.00
```

I can't really understand what is going on in the memory between assigning values and printing them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use regular assignment with char * like that.  You will need to use strcpy.  For example:

```
strcpy(array[i]->name,tok);
```

Otherwise you are making all the array[i]->name point to the same string.

Comment: how would i handle the string to double?